# app name in python import path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

How do I use "relative static" paths in my import path

For example, if I have an app named asdf, with the following directory

```
asdf/
 +- asdf/
 |   +- main.py
 |   +- config.py
 +- tests/
 etc.
```

Currently I have in my main.py...

```
from config import Config
```

I want to be able to use...

```
from asdf.config import Config
```

The reason why is that the modules are getting moved around as the project is still in its infancy, relatively speaking. (no pun intended)

Comment: Could you please clarify, what did you mean by `asdf.config`, If that's what you want consider moving the `config.py` inside another `asdf` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find a workaround this problem. But presence of modules/folders with same name as its parent always causes issues, especially when both the parent and child module are in python path. Since django1.6, django also names project folder and internal folder similarly, which causes lot of issues, especially in testing.

So as a norm try to avoid naming modules same as parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
asdf/
 +- asdf/
 |   +- asdf/
 |       config.py
 |   +- main.py
 +- tests/
 etc.
```

if you have this directory structure then you can import Config method of config.py at main.py using this `from asdf.config import Config`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer (or possibly just a workaround).

If I "compile" it with setuptools it will work.